# Unable to plot brackets above grouped box plots using stat_compare_means

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I'm trying to plot grouped box plots with ggplot2 where the significance values (calculated with Wilcox test) will be displayed above the compared pairs. This seems to be straightforward however using `stat_compare_means` function I'm able to plot only p-values while the brackets below them are missing.

Here is the code to reproduce the dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Group = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each = 8 ), 
           Sex = rep(c(rep("F", 5), rep("M", 3)), 4), 
           Sample = rep(1:8, 4), 
           Value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12.55,  0,  2.42, 9.68, 5.81, 7.51, 8.23, 
                     6.42, 0, 5.30, 2.04, 34.00, 27.52, 30.72, 36.11, 34.79, 
                     13.81, 38.52, 19.03, 0, 5.13, 0, 2.72, 1.99, 0, 0, 0))
```

I'm using the following code to create the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

ggplot(df, aes(x = Group, y = Value, fill = Sex)) +
      stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.55, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
      geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) + theme_minimal() +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1), legend.position = "none") + 
      scale_fill_manual(values = c("F" = "#A6CEE3", "M" = "palevioletred2")) +
      stat_compare_means(aes(group = Sex), label = "p.format", method = "wilcox.test", bracket.size = 2, label.y = 42)
```

So despite of providing `bracket.size` the brackets are still missing and the plot looks like this:

[image: grouped_boxplots]

The final plot could look like this (the brackets could be the square one or just line):

[image]

Comment: Where do you want the brackets? Can you describe how it should look like?

Comment: @DimitriosZacharatos the bracket should be placed just below the p-values. It could have a square bracket shape or a straight line.

Comment: Now I see what you mean brackets with the second image

Answer (score 1):

I think this might help you:

```
library(ggpubr)

ggplot(df_test, aes(x = Group, y = Value, fill = Sex)) +
    stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.55, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
    geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) + theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1), legend.position = "none") + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("F" = "#A6CEE3", "M" = "palevioletred2")) +
    geom_bracket(xmin=0.75,xmax=1.2,y.position = 40,label="p=0.079",inherit.aes = F)+
    geom_bracket(xmin=1.75,xmax=2.2,y.position = 40,label="p=0.036",inherit.aes = F)+
    geom_bracket(xmin=2.75,xmax=3.2,y.position = 40,label="p=5.71",inherit.aes = F)+
    geom_bracket(xmin=3.75,xmax=4.2,y.position = 40,label="p=0.172",inherit.aes = F)
```

I believe the problem here is that you're trying to tell ggplot to draw a bracket between group A and group A (in the x-axis), it will draw something but of length=0 so you need to specify the x-axis coordinates

This one will give you the same but without brackets, just lines:

```
ggplot(df_test, aes(x = Group, y = Value, fill = Sex)) +
    stat_boxplot(geom = "errorbar", width = 0.55, position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
    geom_boxplot(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) + theme_minimal() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = 1), legend.position = "none") + 
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("F" = "#A6CEE3", "M" = "palevioletred2")) +
    geom_segment(aes(x=0.75, xend=1.2, y=40, yend=40)) + 
    geom_segment(aes(x=1.75, xend=2.2, y=40, yend=40)) + 
    geom_segment(aes(x=2.75, xend=3.2, y=40, yend=40)) +
    geom_segment(aes(x=3.75, xend=4.2, y=40, yend=40)) +
    annotate("text",label="p=0.079",x=1,y=41) +
    annotate("text",label="p=0.036",x=2,y=41) +
    annotate("text",label="p=0.571",x=3,y=41) +
    annotate("text",label="p=0.172",x=4,y=41)
```

These are the plots produced by both codes:

[image: First code]

[image: Second code]

Comment: Thanks @Sushiroll, it's not exactly the solution that I seek but it is still an improvement of what I came up with. I'm a bit confused how the stat_compare_means works because its performance is not consistent: it cannot draw bracket between groupA-groupA but still manages to print p-values between them.

Comment: Hey @ahaswer,

   I've uploaded the produced graphs with both codes, I thought that was something like what you were looking for. Could you give us more details on your expected output so we can try and help?
Regarding the p-values, I guess this is because in this case it just has to print a value and not a line with start and end coordinates

Comment: The graphs you posted are exactly what I'm looking for. My only concern is that the code will became cumbersome when I have to specify several p-values manually.

Comment: Ohh, I understand now, sorry. I guess you could make a df out of the several p-values without great effort and the some calculations to get the ranges of xmin and xmax but that would take longer than the actual plotting. Maybe contacting the developers of ggpubr would be best at this point